# How to get the kernel mode time and user mode time in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using Windows 7. How to find the kernel mode time and user mode time for a process in PowerShell? I was able to get the process name and process ID.

```
$strComputer = "."
$procs = Get-Process -ComputerName $strComputer
foreach ($proc in $procs) {
    if ($proc.ProcessName -eq "notepad") {
        echo $proc.Id
        echo $proc.ProcessName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel mode time:

```
$proc.PrivilegedProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds
```

User mode time:

```
$proc.UserProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds
```

For discovery purposes you can use `$proc | Get-Member` to enumerate the (non-hidden) methods and properties of an object, and `$proc | Format-List *` to list all (non-hidden) properties and their values.

Or, you could simply check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).